# How to track the time taken for each function in a route in Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, logging

Right now I am trying to capture statistics of every request in flask, I am able to capture the time taken for a request to complete. Is there a way to capture the time taken for each function inside a route.

```
MY Code capturing the time taken by a route
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_func(response):
    print("tearing down reqest")
    print("Request",request)
    required_data = {
        "path": request.full_path,
        "url": request.url,
        "json_data": request.get_json(),
        "start": request.start_time,
        "stop": dt.utcnow(),
        "total_elapsed_time": (dt.utcnow() - request.start_time).total_seconds()
    }
    print("request data",required_data)
    return response

def call_func():
    sleep(5)
    print("FunctionCalled")

def another_func():
    sleep(5)
    print("FunctionCalled2")


@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello2():
    time.sleep(10)
    call_func()
    another_func()
    return 'Hello World'
```

How do I calcualte that call_func() and another_func() took 5 seconds seach in the execution of that route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a decorator around functions you wish to time. The decorator will then add the name of the function with the elapsed running time of the function to a dictionary kept in the application global `g` attribute `timings`. This can be logged in a `teardown_request` or `after_request` hook or, as is done here, by the `/` view function:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, g
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    g.timings = {}

from functools import wraps
def time_this(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        g.timings[func.__name__] = end - start
        return r
    return wrapper


@time_this
def call_func():
    time.sleep(1)

@time_this
def another_func():
    time.sleep(2)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello2():
    call_func()
    another_func()
    return Response('Hello World: ' + str(g.timings), mimetype='text/plain')
```

**Update**

I just want to make the point that when you time a view function, the timing will not be created and added to the `timings` dictionary until after the function returns, so in that case the `timings` dictionary is best processed in an `after_request` hook function, for example:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request_func(response):
    # just append timings to the output response:
    response.data += ('\n' + str(g.timings)).encode('ascii')
    return response

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@time_this
def hello2():
    call_func()
    another_func()
    return Response('Hello World', mimetype='text/plain')
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World
{'call_func': 1.0014231204986572, 'another_func': 2.0004665851593018, 'hello2': 3.001889705657959}
```